# Return category slug / title from category ID

Tags: categories, custom-field, query-posts, taxonomy, slug

I have a custom field set up that returns the category ID of a chosen category, I'm looking to use this category ID to show, in one instance: category slug, and another instance: category title.
The field get's called quite simply like so: `<?php the_field('category_test'); ?>` and returns the ID, in this case `4`.
Is it at all possible to use this field to return the category slug, and also use it to return the category title? I'm not really sure how or if this can be done. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`get_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category) will return all the information you need for both cases.

```
$catinfo = get_category(get_field('category_test'));
```

From the Codex, that will give you (sample data obviously):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 85
    [name] => Category Name
    [slug] => category-name
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 85
    [taxonomy] => category
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 70
    [count] => 0
    [cat_ID] => 85
    [category_count] => 0
    [category_description] => 
    [cat_name] => Category Name
    [category_nicename] => category-name
    [category_parent] => 70
)
```

I am pretty sure that [`get_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/) is correct.

`get_category` works correctly for every category ID that I've tried, and `NULL` for bad category IDs but per the discussion below, [`get_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/) can return an array. When this happens `get_category` appears to return the first category in the database by ID which is the `uncategorized` category by default. That can be demonstrated with the following.

```
var_dump(get_category(array(8,9,10)));
```

Therefore, to compensate you will need:

```
$cat_field = get_field('category_test');
if (is_array($cat_field)) {
  $cat_field = $cat_field[0];
}
$catinfo = get_category($cat_field);
```

To get any particular field just use standard object syntax. Fpr example:

```
echo $catinfo->slug;
```

Or

```
$cname = $catinfo->name;
```

Comment: ah this almost works, although for some reason it's returning an array for the `Uncategorized` category, even though the ID being passed is from another category?

Comment: ACF can return an array of values especially when you're using taxonomy fields. You probably need to use something like `$category = get_field('category_test');` and then `$catinfo = get_category( $category[0] );`

Comment: @RRikesh This doesn't seem to return anything? The method above returns an array, but not for the right category, only showing `Uncategorized` for some reason.

Comment: @RRikesh I've also tried `function get_cat_slug($cat_id) {
$cat_id = (int)$cat_id;
$category = &get_category($cat_id);
return $category->slug;
}` in functions.php and `<?php echo get_cat_slug(get_field('category_test')); ?>` in the test page and even though the `category_test` field returns the ID of `4` the slug that is being returned is of the `uncategorized` category again :(

Comment: @s_ha_dum  
ah this almost works, although for some reason it's returning an array for the Uncategorized category, even though the ID being passed is from another category?

Comment: @user1374796 : see the edit